# Implementing Depth First Search in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have a homework where I need to implement a DFS in java.
this pseudocode was given for task 1.

```
DFS(V,E,s)

foreach u ∈ V
    vis(u) <-- 0
    p[u] <-- NULL

DFS-Visit(u)
    vis(u) <-- 1

work through u here foreach neighbor v to u
if vis(u) = 0
    p[v] = u
DFS-Visit(v)
```

And so far this is what I got:

```
package kth.id2010.lab.lab05;

public class DFS {
    private static boolean[] visited;
    private static int[] path;

    static void DFS(int vertecies[], int edges[], int sourceVertex){

        for(int i = 0; i < vertecies.length; i++){
            visited[i] = false;
            dfsVisit(i);
        }

    }
    static void dfsVisit(int u){
        visited[u] = true;
    }
}
```

So if I have thought corectly I have gotten to the part where I need to work through u foreach neighbor v to u. 
And I'm not entierly sure how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, stack isn't here to do your homework, it's a fairly well known rule. What we can do is help you get through a specific task or programming bug. What have you attempted? Start small and go from there. There is much more to DFS than to just iterate through each neighbor. You're right that the idea is to expand each neighbor but what do you do once you expand it? You may want to look into the Queue object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: How can you represent the edges as an array of int? Each edge requires two integers (for its two vertices).

Comment: You could use an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @ZekeDroid I know that stack isn't here to do my homework, and I never asked stack to solve my homework I only asked for help on a specific portion of my homework.

Comment: @michaelgulak I'm not sure if what I'm about to say is correct but from what I have gathered adjacency matrix wont make my program recursive? and I need it to be recursive atleast for task 1 of my homework task 2 is to make it not recursive. I know I never stated that in my question so hard for you to know right :)

Comment: An adjacency matrix just describes the structure of a graph, and in one of its simpler forms, would just be a 2D array of booleans. Said array indicates an edge between vertices `i` and `j` by having a value of `true` at `adjacencyMatrix[i][j]`. How your code interacts with it is up to you -- it could be recursive or iterative.

Comment: @michaelgulak alright, I'll give it a try. Just had an Illussion that the way you use adjacencyMatrix was to make it not recursive and that was it, but guess that was wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make it not recursive." An adjacency matrix is a means of representing a graph, not of traversing one.

Comment: Necrozze isn't thinking about the representation of the nodes yet, when learning about DFS in class we are usually taught the theory before the implementation, overlooking the practical way of actually respresenting the nodes. It's what this exercise will hopefully help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, if it's just the iteration through neighbors then here is a place to start:

DFS means you want to expand a node all the way before moving on to the second neighbor so, as you were probably taught, it's a first-in last-out approach. In practical terms, you can start with an empty [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) object and add the first node to it using Stack.push(). Then you can do a `while !Stack.empty(): Stack.pop()`. This will remove the last element inserted. You then iterate through each element recursively (call this method in the for loop) and repeat until you run out of neighbors at which point just return nothing.

The question is now what are these 'elements'? If you are pushing arrays of `[start,end]` then when you pop it, what are the neighbors that you need to feed back on to the recursion? Well if you think about it a bit you will realize that the neighbors of a node with this representation would be all nodes whose `end` point of the parent node matches the `start` point of any other node (that wasn't visited).

The naive way of implementation, which is a good way to start, would be the following (pseudo code):

```
while (!Stack.empty()):
    current_node = Stack.pop();
    foreach node in all_nodes:
        if current_node[1] == node[0] and node.not_visited_yet(): Stack.push(node)
    // now we have the neighbors for this current_node pushed into the Stack
    // Note that node.not_visited_yet() could be a function that keeps track of nodes
    // that you already visited somehow (a map from node to boolean perhaps?)
```

That's really it as far as traversing your tree. Of course all this does is traverse, it doesn't do anything meaningful, but that wasn't your question. If you wanted to, for example, return a string when a particular node was reached, just add it below the for loop. You could also make this a function that takes in the node and the stack and not use a while loop but rather return once you reach your end goal.

```
function DFS (Stack, current_node): // recursive
    current_node = Stack.pop();
    foreach node in all_nodes:
        if current_node[1] == node[0] and node.not_visited_yet(): Stack.push(node)
    if not Stack.empty:
        next_node = Stack.pop()
        return DFS(Stack, next_node)
```